# Why my jQuery on click event not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console, click

I am trying to make a navigation button click event, but the jQuery on click event doesn't seem to function properly. When I click the button, it is supposed to log a message to the console. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log("It's Working Jim!");
    });
});
```

The `dropdown-toggle` class is applied to a div containing text (I have also tried using a span), and the `dropdown` class is applied to a `li` that contains the div. I have looked through at least 15 other similar threads before deciding to post myself.

Thanks in advance,
Harris Mirza.

Answer (score 0):

if the `.dropdown-toggle` elements are added dynamically ( which I assume they do), then you must delegate your event to that element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $(document).on('click','.dropdown-toggle', function (event) {
        console.log("It's Working Jim!");
    });
});
```

all of that is possible presuming that you're using the right version of jQuery (i.e. your jQuery supports `on()`)

Answer (score 0):

It is working

If you are trying to make it work on mobile device, I would suggest to use on 'vclick' event.

See Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/m3Q5F/

```
<div class= "dropdown-toggle">
        on click
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log("It's Working Jim!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hi could you show your html or tell me are you using right jquery version which support on function. its working fine. on dynamically added div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('ul li').append("<div class= 'dropdown-toggle'> on click </div> ");

    $('ul li div.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log("It's Working Jim!");
    });
});
```

here is my jsfiddle link 
    http://jsfiddle.net/m3Q5F/1/